# writeChan overwrites or queues up

Tags: concurrency, haskell

Following thing is stated in the RWH book:

> If a `Chan` is empty, `readChan` blocks until there is a value to read.
>   The `writeChan` function never blocks: it writes a new value into a `Chan`
>   immediately.

What is not clear to me is whether a call to `writeChan` will overwrite the already existing message (assuming some message isn't already read) or will it queue up the message in proper order so that the unread message isn't lost ?

Comment: I'm not going to post this as an answer because I'm not 100% sure this is correct, but my understanding is that a `Chan` is basically a queue, you shove data in one side and it comes out the other.  You could test this pretty easily.  I would recommend checking out the Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell book by Simon Marlow, I remember that he walks through the implementation of `MVar`s and `Chan`s, among other things.

Comment: You can also look at the implementation which is only a few lines and pretty clever

Comment: For the lazy: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/Control-Concurrent-Chan.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It queues up. `Chan` is a channel, in which messages can be queued. By comparison `MVar` can instead take just one value, behaving as a variable and not as a queue.